# How to combine 2 macros into 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA Macros. I recorded/created the below Macros. When I run the Macros independently, they do run. However, when I try to combine them, then Macro 2 throws an error. Find below the Macros. Any help would be appreciated. TIA!

[image]

Comment: `FiltertolastNDays` needs passed an argument.

Comment: Please don't post images of code

Comment: @BigBen Can you please elaborate? In which line of Code should I make the change?

Comment: The line `FilterToLastNDays`.

Comment: You're doing it correct in FilterLast60Days, you're not doing it correct in Macro2, i.e. `FilterToLastNDays 60` is correct for 60 days.

Comment: Remove `FilterToLastNDays` from Macro2.  _OR_  remove `FolterToLast60Days` from Macro2 and change other line to `FilterToLastNDays 60`. In short, the purpose of both line are same.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Sub Macro2()
Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter

FilterLast60Days
FilterToLastNDays 30 ' Instead of the 30 you can past what ever value you want

End Sub

Sub FilterLast60Days()
FilterToLastNDays 60
End Sub

Sub FilterToLastNDays(N As Integer)
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$H$1").EntireColumn
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & Date - N, Operator:=xlAnd, 
Criteria2:="<=" & Date
End With
End Sub
```